# apache chown on its files not working

Tags: bash, apache, chown

My apache user generate one file :

```
# ls -lsa /tmp/reference_file.csv
76 -rwxrwxrwx  1 apache apache 69921 Aug 16 14:14 /tmp/reference_file.csv
```

the user and the group belong to apache, but when i am trying to change it :

```
 su -l apache -s /bin/bash
-bash-3.00$ whoami
apache
-bash-3.00$ chown explorer:btunix /tmp/reference_file.csv
chown: changing ownership of `/tmp/reference_file.csv': Operation not permitted
```

I tried to another folder, but the result was the same, I ve also checked attribut :

```
 # lsattr /tmp/reference_file.csv
 ------------- /tmp/reference_file.csv
```

there is no immutable attribut

How can I do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are criteria associated with chown.  Only super-user can chown files willy-nilly. Whether you can give away a file that you own depends on your UNIX flavor and how associated kernel configuration parameters (like K_CHOWN_MAY_GIVE_AWAY, for argument's sake) may have been, well, configured.  This is the most GENERALLY correct answer.